# Customize theme breaking search functionality in typedoc

Tags: typescript, typedoc

When I created own customize theme in typedoc, observed search functionlity is broken. I don't understand why is this happening. Appreciate your help in advance.

By theme I mean, added own css and javascript to manipulate DOM.

Reference https://typedoc.org/guides/themes/

Comment: Can you add more details as to how you created your own theme?

Comment: @chic Thanks for the comment, I have added more details. Hope make sense now.

Comment: Do you have a public repository showing your code? It is hard to know what is going on from the information you provided.